# Pass a variable from foreground to background in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, background-process

I am developing an iOS application where I want to record the time when a user presses a particular button and keep it. Later I will use this time record in background. Is there a nice way of doing that without invoking NSUserDefaults or CoreData or whatever other database?

I am very new to iOS development. I think this is very likely to be a naive question. But I'm just curious. Please don't laugh at me haha.

**Edit:** This is indeed a very naive question haha.

Comment: It depends if you want the data to persist - Do you want the data to be available after the app has been killed and run again?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be persistent. @Wezly

Comment: Does the data need to be available across a number of classes or is it only required in one? - I kinda assume it's the first option and the data needs to be persist for the duration of the app session?

Comment: The time is recorded when a button in a UIViewController is tabbed and it is later used in background( in AppDelegate). To my knowledge it is across classes. But it's even better if there is a way to do it within only one class. @Wezly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to make sure your data is available everywhere in your app and only persists for each app session would be to use a singleton. *Something like this.*

```
// Create a class to store the data
class SessionData : NSObject {

    // Create a shared instance of your class
    static let sharedInstance = SessionData()

    // Create a variable to store the date object
    var timeStore:NSDate?
}
```

This will mean that anywhere in your app you can `get` and `set` this data *as below.*

```
// Get
if let time = SessionData.sharedInstance.timeStore {
    println(time)
}

// Set
SessionData.sharedInstance.timeStore = NSDate()
```

---

*It is worth mentioning that despite the above being a valid method, You may be able to avoid doing this by re-thinking your app structure and passing data between classes instead.* You should have a look at [Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID276).

*Also as @CouchDeveloper mentions in their comment below, you may want to included a dispatch queue to prevent crashes or locks in the situation where two or more classes try to read and or write data at the same time.*

Comment: Concurrent access to shared resources (e.g. variables, properties) requires to use synchronization primitives (mutexes, locks, etc.). Alternatively use a dedicated dispatch_queue. Otherwise, your code introduces  a "data race".